# Approval workflow with the possibility to add another person after it's closed

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

i have an approval workflow for a library with 20 approvers, when the document is approved you might have to add a new approvers who obviously has to approve the document , there is a system to reopen the workflow or simply add a new person to a approval process?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you can't re-open a completed workflow, you will need to do this with a second workflow / running the same workflow again.

I'm assuming that you have a method in your current approval workflow to select who needs to approve the document, so you would need to re-run this workflow with the additional approver.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, i want to re-run the workflow only for the additional approver, becouse all the other approver have already approved the document.